# Regular Expression required

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to write a regular expression that should allow standard characters `[a-zA-Z0-9]` plus one space between each word, the umlauts `[äöüÄÖÜ]`, a dot (`.`) and a hyphen (`-`) and no other special characters.

**For Example :**

Following should be allowed:

```
Dr. Aaryan Joshi    
Phill Rozer MSc.    
Ajay Verma5    
Rajan-Verma MSc.
```

---

And following should not be allowed:

```
Ajay     Verma
Dr. Ajay. Verma.
Test Name.-.Name2
```

Comment: can the string started with a number character?

Comment: And what have you tried yourself?

Comment: @You Qi Choong : Yes it can start with numbers also

Comment: What make this `Dr. Aaryan Joshi` and `Phill Rozer MSc.` a valid string but not this `Dr. Ajay. Verma.`?

Comment: @You Qi Choong : Only one DOT(.) is allowed in the string.

Comment: Is the period allowed anywhere, or just at the end of words? Is `This is.a test` valid?

Comment: What about Dr. Med. Bla ? Isn't this a perfectly valid name?

Comment: @Guffa : Yes DOT(.) is allowed anywhere

Comment: @FailedDev : Yes Dr. Med. Bla is 100% a valid name, but I need max. one dot in entire string...

Comment: @Pushpendra that has 2 dots :D

Comment: @FailedDev : Yes, Of course and it is not allowed in this case...

Comment: Do you need **one** regex? Could you use a function instead (with more than one regex)?

Comment: @Adriana : Yes off-course we can use function...

Comment: Would be a whole level easier if you specified *precisely* what you want to achieve, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (in JavaScript, to match your comment above)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // All "true"
            alert(test("Dr. Aaryan Joshi"));
            alert(test("Phill Rozer MSc."));
            alert(test("Ajay Verma5"));
            alert(test("Rajan-Verma MSc."));

            // All "false"
            alert(test("Ajay     Verma"));
            alert(test("Dr. Ajay. Verma."));
            alert(test("Test Name.-.Name2"));

            function test( name ) {
                var pattern = /^(?=[^.]*\.?[^.]*$)(?!.* $)([A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜ.-]+( |$))+$/;
                /*
                 * (?=[^.]*\.?[^.]*$)
                 *  - Contains zero or one dots (.)
                 * (?!.* $)
                 * - Does not end with a space (as in stema's answer)
                 * ([A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜ.-]+( |$))
                 * - Matches chars specified, ending with one space or end of string
                 * 
                 * (Whole pattern is anchored to start & end of string too)
                 */
                return pattern.test(name);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
^(?! )(?!.* $)(?=[^.]*\.?[^.]*$)(?=[^-]*-?[^-]*$)(?!.*? {2,})[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ .-]+$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v4hr)

`^` and `$` are [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) that matches the start and the end of the string

`[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ .-]+` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) with a quantifier (`+` => 1 or more) this part matches all characters you want to allow.

The `(?!)` and `(?=)`  are [negative/positive look aheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). They verify the conditions you set.

`(?! )` Does not start with a space
`(?!.* $)` Does not end with a space
`(?=[^.]*\.[^.]*$)` Only one dot allowed, anywhere in the string
`(?=[^-]*-[^-]*$)` Only one dash allowed, anywhere in the string
`(?!.*?  +)` more than one space in sequence is not allowed

Comment: For each string for eg. "Tester12", "Dr. Test Test" etc., it is returning false...

Comment: My regex is matching them [see it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v4hu), how do you use it?

Comment: var pattern = new RegExp(/^(?! )(?!.* $)(?=[^.]*\.[^.]*$)(?=[^-]*-[^-]*$)(?!.*?  +)[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ .-]+$/);
            return pattern.test(name);

Comment: Just poking my head in here to let you know that I've come across certain differences in AS regular expressions and JavaScript. Maybe the issue is there.

Comment: Try this `var pattern = new RegExp("^(?! )(?!.* $)(?=[^.]*\.?[^.]*$)(?=[^-]*-?[^-]*$)(?!.*?  +)[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ .-]+$");` I added two `?` to make the dot and the dash optional. I tested it on [writecodeonline.com/](http://writecodeonline.com/javascript/), hope it works now.

Comment: @stema You negative lookahead for spaces does not allow even a single space to occur in the text. It should be `(?!.*? {2,})`

Comment: @Narendra, no, I do have two spaces in my regex, the plus belongs to the second one. But your expression ` {2,}` is more obvious.

Comment: @stema The updated regex in your comment above has one space while the previous regex in your answer has two spaces.

Comment: @Narendra, thanks, I didn't noticed. I updated the answer with your suggestion to make it more clear.

Comment: Note: There is a difference between space and whitespace. Use `\s` if you really mean whitespace.

Comment: @Guffa sure I fixed my explanation in the question, I mean only space.

Comment: You should use is as `var rx = /^..../;` in JavaScript. The RegExp constructor is for situations when you build then on the fly based on some dynamic factors such as user input, route declaration etc. Plus you don't have to double escape special characters. `/\s/` == `new RegExp('\\s')`

Comment: The examples are good, but (?!.*? +) doesn't make sense since .* and ? cancel each other out.

Comment: @StefanZCamilleri What do you mean with "cancel each other out"? `.*?` is a perfectly valid ungreedy quantifier matching 0 or more.

Comment: As you say, the kleene closure * means '0 or more', whilst ? means '0 or 1 of the previous match group.

So .* and .*? mean exactly the same thing.. so the ? is redundant.

Comment: @StefanZCamilleri NO `.*` and `.*?` do not mean the same. When the `?` is placed after another quantifier it is not 0 or 1 anymore, it makes the previous quantifier "lazy". While `.*` is greedy and matches as much as possible is `.*?` lazy and matches as less as possible. [see www.regular-expressions.info for more info about quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it's easier to specify what's not allowed.  The following finds an unapproved character, two consecutive spaces, and more than 2 dots or hyphens.

```
([^a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ. -]|  |\..*\.|-.*-)
```

If spaces are not allowed at the beginning or end of string you can use:

```
([^a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ. -]|^ | $|  |\..*\.|-.*-)
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is this:

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]+)?\s)*([a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]*\.)|
(\.[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]+))|((([a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]*\.)|(\.[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]+)\s)?
([a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]+)?\s)*[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]+
(-[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]+)?)$
```

**Breaking it down**

A dot-free word with hyphen matches:
Its assumed that a hyphen, if present, is not allowed at the beginning or the end. If this assumption is wrong, it is easy enough to adjust accordingly.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]+-[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]+
```

A dot-free word without hyphen matches:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]+
```

Thus a dot-free word, with or without a single hyphen (and at most one hypen) matches:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]+)?
```

We can make use of a general design pattern (no pun intended), to get exactly one X with any number of Y:

```
(Y*X)|(XY+)
```

So applying this rule, a dotted word with exactly one dot matches:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]*\.)|(\.[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]+)
```

Similarly get a stream of words with exactly one dotted, we slightly modify the general rule for a space separator. So a stream of words with exactly one dotted matches:

```
  ((Y\s)*X)|(X\s(Y\s)*Y)
```

where:
  1. Y = the regex for a dot-free word
  2. X = the regex for a dotted word

Similarly a stream of only dot-free words would match:

```
(Y\s)*Y
```

where Y is as before.

Combining the two meta-regexes, a stream of words with at most one dotted word matches:

```
((Y\s)*X)|((X\s)?(Y\s)*Y)
```

where X and Y are as before.

The final step is to substitute X and Y back in the preceding meta-regex to yield my propoosed solution. The really nice thing about my solution is that it does not use look-aheads, so resolution is faster and it works on all flavours of regex, including even the very primitive flavours from XML Schema, XPATH and XSLT.

Add ^ and $ at the start and end if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In standard regex, you can use the unicode character property classes to capture umlauts (ex. \p{Mn}).

Unfortunately this is not supported in JavaScript Regex, so you need to explicitly specify the characters you want to accept.

**This will therefore do the trick for you**

```
(?:[a-zA-Z\däöüÄÖÜ-]+(?:\.(?!.*\.))?[ ]{0,1})+
```

**If you want to enforce just one hyphen** change it to this

```
(?:[a-zA-Z\däöüÄÖÜ]+(?:\.(?!.*\.))?(?:-(?!.*-)|[ ]{0,1}))+
```

### Explanation

I will break it down, using 'Dr. Aaryan Joshi' as an example.

Anything enclosed in [ ] is what we call a 'character capture group'.  It means capture any of these characters.

For a start, disregard any '?:' for now.. leaving us with ([a-zA-Z\däöüÄÖÜ-]+(\.(?!.*.))?[ ]{0,1})+

So, with [a-zA-Z\däöüÄÖÜ-] we're saying:

- Capture any word character (a-zA-Z0-9), any of these umlauts (äöüÄÖÜ) and any '-'

By adding a + we are saying '1 or more' of these.

This would only match 'Dr' since we are not yet accepting a period or a space character.

Next we add (\.(?!.*\.))? which means:
- match any . (\.) which is **not** followed by another . (?!.(\.))
- we enclose this in brackets followed by a ? which means 'you don't have to match this always'.. i.e. there can or can 'not' be a '.', but if there is, make sure it's the only one.

Now we're matching 'Dr.' but we wouldn't match it if there was another '.' further down the line.

Next we add another character capture group for a space [ ] and use the {,} notation to indicate the 'bounds'.  So [ ]{0,1} means 'match 0 or 1 space' (an alternative notation to this is using the ? symbol, ex. [ ]? or simply ' ?'.. but the {0,1} is more explicit.

This would now match 'Dr. '.

The last step is to indicate that we want to capture multiple instances of this.  So we wrap it all up in brackets, and use the + to indicate that we want to capture '1 or more' of these.

Which would now match the whole string 'Dr. Aaryan Joshi'

As a final touch, we add '?:' to all the capture groups to indicate that we are only matching patterns and do not want to store a reference to the matched groups (saves memory :))

Further to @AlanMoore's comments, you can of course also add anchors to this regex like so

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z\däöüÄÖÜ]+(?:\.(?!.*\.))?(?:-(?!.*-)|[ ]{0,1}))+$
```

Should you want to set a minimum limit to the amount of characters accepted, then change the first plus to a bound.. ex {3,} to say '3 or more'.

Hope this helps :)

**Note** I've tested all these against the acceptance criteria you gave, and it matches all cases when using the JavaScript regex engine :)

**Edit** Swapped out `\w` to `a-zA-Z\d` since `\w` would also accept the `_` character (Thank you @AlanMoore for pointing that out)

Comment: Your regex would allow any amount of dashes per word, but the OP wants only one dash in the complete Name, the same criteria than for the dot.

Comment: I don't see that specified, yet if that is the case, it is a simple change -> (?:[\wäöüÄÖÜ]+(?:\.(?!.*\.))?(?:-(?!.*-)|[ ]{0,1}))+ I'll add a note :)

Comment: That doesn't work.  Everything in that regex is optional except the first character class (*not* "character capture group"--there's no such thing).  All it's required to match is one letter or digit (or an underscore; `\w` matches those as well). Without anchors at both ends it's meaningless, and *with* anchors it doesn't match any of the "good" examples.

Comment: That is wrong, as you imply, it matches all of the examples without anchors, plus I tested it, and at no point does he specify that 1 character is not allowed.  As for adding anchors, that is optional and depends on how he wants to match.

Comment: If on the other hand it is specified that there needs to be at least 3 characters, or at least two words... I can adjust it accordingly.

Comment: Just for the sake of comprehensiveness, I have tested the regex by just adding anchors, and it is correct for all the examples given.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(([\wäöüÄÖÜ]+|[\wäöüÄÖÜ]+\-[\wäöüÄÖÜ]+)\.?\s?)+$/.test(yourString)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(?=[^.]+(?:\.[^.]*)?$)(?=[^-]+(?:-[^-]*)?$)[A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜ.-]+(?:[ ][A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜ.-]+)*$/
```

These are the criteria as I understand them:

1. Must start with a letter or a digit (including those accented letters).
2. May have at most one dot (`'.'`), which can be anywhere but the beginning.
3. May have at most one hyphen (`'-'`), ditto.
4. May contain any number spaces, but they can't be at the beginning or end, and they must not be consecutive.
5. May contain any number of alphanumeric characters from the set `[A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]` as long as the other criteria are met.  That is, there has to be at least one alphanumeric at beginning (rule 1) and at least one following each space, if there are any (rule 4).

And here's a breakdown of the regex:

```
^
(?=[^.]+(?:\.[^.]*)?$)      # at most one dot, not at the beginning
(?=[^-]+(?:-[^-]*)?$)       # at most one hyphen, ditto
[A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜ.-]+        # first "word"
(?:
  [ ]                       # space presaging another "word"
  [A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜ.-]+      # the next "word"
)*
$
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ\-]+\.?.[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ\-]+(.[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ\-]+)?\.?$
```

remember use slash after and before in javascript